# Display a div according to changing $rootScope variable value

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a http call every 10 seconds and then display a div if the rootScope.mailSent is equel to true.  The call is well done.

In my controller I have done that :

```
    $interval(function(){
        $http.get("/api/sentMails")
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.length>0){
                $rootScope.mailSent = true;
            }
        });
    }.bind($rootScope), 10000);
```

In my view :

```
<div ng-show="{{mailSent === true}}" class="pastille" ng-cloak=""></div>
```

But the div never shows whereas the mailSent value is true.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need `{{}}` in `ng-show` because it accepts an expression.

Comment: did you try to console.log($rootScope.mailSent) every time the request is done?

Comment: And yes @MuliYulzary is right, that you don't need `{{}}` in `ng-show`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect, try this:

```
<div ng-show="mailSent" class="pastille" ng-cloak=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div ng-show="mailSent" class="pastille" ng-cloak=""></div>
```

ng-show will take true or false value. If mail sent you have set "$rootScope.mailSent = true;". So ng-show will get true value.No need to do comparison like this.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `{{}}` with ng-show Try this:

```
<div ng-show="mailSent === true" class="pastille" ng-cloak=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using directly a field under $rootScope may cause a lot of trouble. For instance all the solution given will not work if i wrapped their solution in another div having the `ng-if` directive.

In order to make sure that won't happen use an intermediary field and **don't forget** to initialize it. Since it's in the rootScope initialize it in an `angular.run` block.

Finally : ng-show take an expression as parameter no interpolation (brackets).

```
<div ng-show="mail.sent == true" class="pastille"></div>
 $rootScope.mail = {sent:false};// initialize this in the controller pass it to true when you have the condition met
```

Comment: just something i'm used too with angular & forms to have a fail-fast when i get true or false as string instead of boolean values :)

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have pointed out, it appears to be a scoping issue. If you attach `$log` to your scope you can call it in the template. Here's a nifty trick:

```
<button data-ng-click="$log.log(put your model variable here)"></button>
```

If you add that to your template, then you can click it and you will get a log in the console of what is inside that variable.

If you are not using `controllerAs` syntax, I highly recommend it to avoid variable shadowing. You can do that in your `$routeProvider` code, or in your template when you declare your controller.

Then your reference would be `scopeName.mailSent`

Then your button would look like this:

```
<button data-ng-click="scopeName.$log.log(scopeName.mailSent)"></button>
```